# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'aux.h': Permission denied

Tags: c, visual-studio, opengl

I copied the following code from OpenGL's Redbook ([Chapter 4: Display Lists](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter04.html)) into my editor (Visual Studio Express Edition 2008), named it `list.c` and got compilation error.

```
#include "aux.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>


GLuint listName = 1;

void myinit (void)
{
glNewList (listName, GL_COMPILE);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex2f (0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2f (1.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2f (0.0, 1.0);
        glEnd ();
        glTranslatef (1.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEndList ();
    glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}

void drawLine (void)
{
    glBegin (GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f (0.0, 0.5);
        glVertex2f (15.0, 0.5);
    glEnd ();
}

void display(void)
{
    GLuint i;
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        glCallList (listName);
    drawLine ();
    glFlush ();
}

void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w <= h) 
        gluOrtho2D (0.0, 2.0, -0.5 * (GLfloat) h/(GLfloat) w, 
              1.5 * (GLfloat) h/(GLfloat) w);
    else 
        gluOrtho2D (0.0, 2.0 * (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, -0.5,
              1.5); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auxInitDisplayMode (AUX_SINGLE | AUX_RGBA);
    auxInitPosition (0, 0, 400, 50);
    auxInitWindow (argv[0]);
    myinit ();
    auxReshapeFunc (myReshape);
    auxMainLoop(display);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use not aux, nor glaux. They're too old. **GLUT** is much more easier, while many of people use **SDL** or **SFML** (they're more flexible and feature-full than GLUT). You should try SFML - it has lots of features inside, it's lightweight and portable. You should be satisfied using this one =)

Still if you wanna use **GLUT**, here are your problems:

- *glutInit()* should be called before
  any other operations
- *glutInitDisplayMode()* and other
  window functions must be called
  before any drawing

operations

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h >

// rendering function
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin (GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f (0.0, 0.5);
        glVertex2f (15.0, 0.5);
    glEnd ();

    glFlush();
}

// some initializations
void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // initialize GLUT library
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    // set display mode
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    // set initial window size
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);

    // set initial window position
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

    // create the window
    glutCreateWindow("moofoo");

    // do our initialization routines
    init();

    // set function which will be called each frame
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    // enter main rendering loop
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Windows header file.  Fix:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
// etc...
```

Comment: If I replace "aux.h" with <windows.h> I get 2 errors and 5 warnings.

Comment: If I leave "aux.h" adding <windows.h> like you did, I still get the 'cannot include file' error.

Comment: I have no idea what "aux.h" might be.  It is not a standard #include file, although its name resembles the legacy "glaux.h" header.  Maybe something you'll find in the book's download archive.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code placing glutXxx functions instead of auxXxx ones. It compiles but doesn't run, I'd appreciate feedback here:

```
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <windows.h>


GLuint listName = 1;

void myinit (void)
{
glNewList (listName, GL_COMPILE);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex2f (0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2f (1.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2f (0.0, 1.0);
        glEnd ();
        glTranslatef (1.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEndList ();
    glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}

void drawLine (void)
{
    glBegin (GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f (0.0, 0.5);
        glVertex2f (15.0, 0.5);
    glEnd ();
}

void display(void)
{
    GLuint i;
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        glCallList (listName);
    drawLine ();
    glFlush ();
}

void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w <= h) 
        gluOrtho2D (0.0, 2.0, -0.5 * (GLfloat) h/(GLfloat) w, 
              1.5 * (GLfloat) h/(GLfloat) w);
    else 
        gluOrtho2D (0.0, 2.0 * (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, -0.5,
              1.5); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);


    glutInitWindowPosition (100,100);
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    myinit ();
    glutDisplayFunc (display);
    glutReshapeFunc (myReshape);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```